# Plotting a three variable complex function with Maple

Tags: plot, graph, 3d, maple

I am a beginner to `Maple` and I have to plot a three variable function with Maple.
The function I have to graph is a solution to a two dimensional, time dependent PDE :

```
f(x,y,t) = e^{it}sin(2x).sin(4y)
```

I tried using **`implicitplot3d`** as well as **`complexplot3d`** command but it doesn't seem to work.